# Laravel 5.1 Blade - Loop an array until its inner array end

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How do i loop an array (directory listing) until it's nothing to loop on Laravel Blade?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.jpg
    [1] => 1.jpg
    [2] => 2.jpg
    [3] => 3.jpg
    [FolderA] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1.jpg
            [1] => A2.jpg
            [FolderB] => Array
                (
                    [0] => B1.jpg
                    [1] => B2.jpg
                    [2] => B3.jpg
                    [3] => B4.jpg
                )
        )

)
```

On my view.blade.php, I got setup foreach loop on the array,
but I'd no idea how to loop the array endlessly.

```
<ul>
@foreach($dir_files as $dir_name=>$file)
        @if(is_array($file))
           //stuck at here, I cant run a foreach loop inside here right?
           //should I use include?
        @else
            <li>
                <a href="">{{ $file }}</a>
            </li>
        @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Do we have any method to loop the 3level,5level,10level array endlessly using blade?

I'm sure I can loop the array and precompile the `ul li` tag inside an array and then echo out on the blade, but may I know do laravel blade has any method that can perform a loop until the inner array ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with partials. Let's say this code is in a view file called `partials\partial.blade.php`. You can do this:

```
<ul>
@foreach($dir_files as $dir_name=>$file)
        @if(is_array($file))
           @include('partials.partial', ['dir_files' => $file])
        @else
            <li>
                <a href="">{{ $file }}</a>
            </li>
        @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I learnt something new today! didn't know that laravel's `@include` function can do so much stuff instead of just include files only.